# Reducing random uniform int distribution on each pass

Tags: c++, random, set, uniform-distribution

Working on a class that has a block size of 256 elements. And each time my add function is called before I store anything; I want to generate a uniform random int in the range of [0,255]. What I would like to do is before this function finishes to keep track of the previous values used so that the next time through the function the uniform random int distribution will automatically skip those values instead of having to check to see if something is already contained there.

```
template<class T>
class SomeClass {
     struct Node {
         unsigned idx;
         std::shared_ptr<T> pT;

         Node() : idx(-1), pT(nullptr) {}
         Node( unsigned idx_, std::shared_ptr<T>& pT_ ) : idx(idx_), pT(pT_) {}
    }; // Node

private:
     Node m_storage[256];
     static unsigned m_elementCount;
     std::set<unsigned> m_indexesUsed; 
public:
    SomeClass(){}
    ~SomeClass(){}

    void add( T& obj );
}; // SomeClass

template<class T>
unsigned SomeClass<T>::m_elementCount = 0;    

template<class T>
void SomeClass<T>::add( T& obj ) {

    if ( m_elementCount == 256 ) {
        return; // My Code Base Is Bigger - If This Is Full This Array gets pushed into a vector, 
        // and all values get reset to default and we start over.
    }
    Node n;

    // Generate Uniform Random In Distribution In The Range of [0,255]
    // Excluding the Values from m_listIndexesUsed.
    n.idx =  std::uniform_random_int_distribution from [0,255] excluding previous selected numbers
    n.pT = std::make_shared<T>( obj );
    m_storage[n.idx] = n;
    m_indexesUsed.insert( n.idx );
    m_elementCount++;
}
```

Can determining a value between a specified range my case [0,255] be generated where on each consecutive call determine another random value that wasn't already previously chosen with uniform random int distribution? If so, how would this be done?

**EDIT**

After considering some of the comments below, they have brought up a good point. What is really needed in my case is a set of 256 unique key values ranging from 0 - 255 and they need to be randomly shuffled or scrambled. I will give it some thought as how to try to accomplish this, but if any are willing to get a nice example of one, that is acceptable to. I don't mind putting in the work, but sometimes when I get to a point that I can't seem to get past and I begin to spend too much time on it, I just want to get past that point so I can move on.

Comment: Just make an array of 0...255 and `shuffle` it.

Comment: @T.C. No; I have a key generator or table that has predefined values that are stored as an unsigned char in an array of 256. The 1 byte hex value for example `0x03d2` is a look up reference into a 16x16 grid where if you extract it to 2 coord values then the unsigned char pairs hex values are `0x03` and `0xd2` and this will be a stored reference value. My look up table class is already defined and working. My Current class will use this look up table. I don't want the information to be just added linearly. I want them to be placed randomly.

Comment: @T.C. The insertion is a little slower but since its only 256 it's not a performance hit. But the look up and retrieval is quite fast. I'm creating a chaining container that will randomly store the elements. It is kind of like a security feature. Without the pre-generated table, the order of elements would make no sense.

Comment: @T.C. That's what I'm trying to do is to shuffle the index values between 0-255 on each call to the add function but I want to exclude the values that were already chosen so I don't have to do a bunch of if checks.

Comment: I don't think  you want a random number with uniform distribution. I think that you just want a plain old pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: @Pemdas yeah I can consider that since the range is relatively small. I may not need the overhead of the std::random_engine. I could probably just do a basic modulo random function based off of a seed value where that seed value can be from the system time. Only the randomness of it is not very random.

Comment: Yeah, but what you want is not really random either. You want 256 unique numbers randomly aranged, which you can easily accomplish with a random seed to a pseudo random number generator or a "shuffle" algorithm.

Comment: @Pemdas yeah, I I was probably thinking of the wrong thing when I was working on it; I can probably change my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

We have a standard algorithm to shuffle sequences; it's called, well, `shuffle`. So make a sequence of 0...255, shuffle it, then take from the resulting list until you exhaust it, and repeat. Wrap the whole thing into a class template if you want:

```
template<size_t N>
struct index_generator {

    // seeding method for illustration purposes only
    // see http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html
    index_generator() : rng(std::random_device()()) {
        std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), size_t{});
        reset(); 
    }

    explicit operator bool() const { return current < N; }

    // use [] if you don't need the bounds checking
    size_t operator()() { return indices.at(current++); }

    void reset() {
        std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), rng);
        current = 0;
    }
private:
    std::array<size_t, N> indices;
    size_t current;
    std::mt19937 rng;
};
```

Usage is along the lines of

```
index_generator<256> gen; // static(?) data member

// ...
if ( !gen ) {
    // we've exhausted the 256 indices
    // do whatever you need to do
    gen.reset();
    return;
}

Node n;
n.idx =  gen();
// other stuff
```